# Django F expression changes

Tags: python, django, expression

We used to run Django 1.6 with Python 2.7 and one of our models had a field called balance, defined as:

`balance = models.F('gross') + models.F('refunded') - models.F('paid')`

the output of this field would be, for example: DecimalField('1200').

After upgrading to Django 3.2 and Python 3.9.2, balance returns:

`<CombinedExpression: F(gross) + F(refunded) - F(paid)>`

We tried to work around this by replacing balance with:

```
@property
def balance(self):
   return self.gross + self.refunded - self.paid
```

and this worked until we ran into the error:

`FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'balance' into field.`

Does anyone know of the new correct way to keep the same functionality as we had before when using F expression to define balance?

Also, I have seen some help regarding .refresh_from_db(), but when running a shell and executing:

```
o = Order.objects.all().first()
o.balance
```

Output:
`<CombinedExpression: F(gross) + F(refunded) - F(paid)>`

`o.refresh_from_db()`

Output:
`<CombinedExpression: F(gross) + F(refunded) - F(paid)>`

The output remains the same...

Time and patience greatly appreciated fellow coders.

Kindest regards

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried annotations?

```py
from django.db.models import F

order_list = Order.objects.all().annotate(
      balance= F('gross') + F('refunded') + F('paid')
)

print(order_list.first().balance)
```

If they're differnt types, I believe, you've got to wrap it and give it an output type

```py
from django.db.models import F, ExpressionWrapper
from django.db.models import DecimalField

order_list = Order.objects.all().annotate(
      balance=ExpressionWrapper(
          F('gross') + F('refunded') + F('paid'),
          output_field=DecimalField(max_digits=25, decimal_places=2)
      )
)

print(order_list.first().balance)
```

Comment: Hi Nealium, yes I have done that and although it returns what I am asking for: Decimal(some_value), it does not help with the 'cannot resolve keyword balance into field' error, because the column 'balance' technically only exists within order_list and not the actual relation.

Comment: Gotcha.. could you give an example of when this `Cannot resolve keyword 'balance' into field.` pops up?